# Header e Footer em todos relatórios - ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, header, footer

Como colocar o header e o footer padronizados em todos relatórios ReportViewer de minha aplicação asp.net?

Comment: Cara já faz um bom tempo desde a última vez q usei o Report Viewer, mas na época, tinha q colocar o cabeçalho em kd relatório q ia fazer.

Comment: @JuniorS. o que você usa para Relatórios em ASP.NET agora?

Comment: Eliézer, na verdade faz mto tempo que não mexo com relatórios, mas a maioria usa Cristal Reports, porém essa é uma ferramenta paga, não sei informar se possui versão free, mas é mto boa.